# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having a hard time trying to understand vue.js. I'm currently trying to figure out how I can fetch or call the API. I've managed to setup my `index.html` `app.js` can also the packages that are include in the `node_modules`.

When I try to run my file I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` on my console. It says that I need to install vue-resource and add the two lines of code below.

Where do I insert them exactly? Is it inside my app.js? Sorry for my ignorance but I'm still new to Javascript and Vue.js

```
var Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue" ></script>

    <title>article-app</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="vue-app">
      {{ articles }}
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js" ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
var article = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',

    data: {
        articles: ''
    },

    created: function () {
        this.fetchData();
    },        

    methods: {
        fetchData: function () {
            var that = this
            this.$http.get('http://localhost/aim-beta/rest/export/json/article'),
                function (data) {
                    this.articles = data.main.temp;
                }
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: type="text/javascript" in <script> ?

Comment: You can use the es6 `fetch` for simplicity. http://www.ufus.cc/2UXdW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure `vue-resource` in a separate file, named `plugins/vue-resource.js`

```
const Vue = require('vue');
const Resource = require('vue-resource');

Vue.use(Resource);
```

Then require the file in your `app.js`, like so:

```
require('./plugins/vue-resource.js');

new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  data: {
    articles: ''
  },
  created: function () {
    this.fetchData();
  }, 
  methods: {
    fetchData: function () {
      this
        .$http
        .get('http://localhost/aim-beta/rest/export/json/article',
          function (data) {
            this.articles = data.main.temp;
        })
    }
  }
});
```

Thus, your new folder structure will be like so:

```
- index.html
- app.js
+ plugins
  - vue-resource.js
```

Using native JavaScript Fetch API

```
// You don't need vue resources!!!
// require('./plugins/vue-resource.js'); 
// Read more about Fetch API: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch][1]

new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  data: {
    articles: ''
  },
  created: function () {
    this.fetchData();
  }, 
  methods: {
    fetchData: function () {
      fetch('http://localhost/aim-beta/rest/export/json/article', {
        method: 'GET'
      }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.articles = data.main.temp;
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this out. If I have multiple `require` do I need to separate them in different files?

Comment: Yes! Separating them makes your app modular and let's you keep track and configure third party module individually

Comment: However, structuring your app depends on your decision

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: Are you using browserify or Webpack?

Comment: @Noel I have updated the answer to reflect using `fetch API`

Comment: To answer your question, I started with `vue init webpack project-name`. For your second comment I didn't get any error but on my browser nothing is displayed. The API path is working though. I getting JSON data on it

Comment: When using the `Fetch API` can you check the network tab of your developer tools. And make sure your browser supports Fetch Implementation.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I'm using google chrome https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: What’s the status code from the network tab on the developer tools?

Comment: `Request URL:http://localhost/aim-beta/rest/export/json/article` `Status Code:200 OK`

Comment: @Noel could you try another api endpoint maybe, https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users, also is your local server running on port 80? If no add the port after localhost e.g. localhost:3000

Comment: Will try a different endpoint. App is running on `http://127.0.0.1:5500/`

Comment: @Noel the endpoint should be localhost:5500/aim-beta/rest/export/json/article

Comment: Hello @akinjide, was that the issue? `http://localhost/aim-beta/rest/export/json/article` this url is being run by xampp server, and the `http://127.0.0.1:5500/` is being run by a `live-server` extension of visual code studio

Comment: @Noel you’d have to try both and see which gives you a response also check the live-server configuration for the port number it’s emitting

Comment: I tried the commands `npm run dev` and it throws me into a welcome page with a url `http://localhost:8080/#/` :(

Comment: Yeah! It’s working, you can start adding your components and configure axios or vue-resources

Comment: @akinjide Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529345/how-can-i-solve-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-get-of-undefined-in